# how to display the varchar field data 26/06/2017 without slash in formula field of Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

database field Varchar , data is 26/06/2017

need to fetch the data in crystal report without backward slash, end data that need to be reflected in report should be 26062017.

I am using below ToText ({Tablename.ColumnName}, '#/'). Don't know where I am wrong, pls help.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a text field you can use the replace function

```
replace({Tablename.ColumnName},"/","")
```

But if you have a datetime field you can right click the fiels and select **Format Field** on the Date and Time tab select Customize and than the date tab, in the separators box select the first and second formula editor button and write "" in the formula. So you will get a ddMMyyyy format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Totally Agree with Raphael. One more way to achieve to this as pass the date time field in the report and make below modification in format object.
[Click Hear to see the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp74Q.png)